# How to add CSP headers to an AWS CDK setup?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk, content-security-policy

I am currently working on a project where I am deploying a front-end application to an S3 bucket and then serving it with CloudFront. I am using AWS CDK to set this up. Here is my current configuration:

```
new BucketDeployment(this, `deployment-${context.environment}`, {
  sources: [Source.asset("../Frontend")],
  destinationBucket: frontBucket,
});

const cfDist = new cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, `${context.appName}-dist-${context.environment}`, {
  originConfigs: [
    {
      s3OriginSource: {
        s3BucketSource: frontBucket,
      },
      behaviors: [
        {
          isDefaultBehavior: true,
          defaultTtl: cdk.Duration.seconds(1)
        },
      ]
    },
  ],
  viewerProtocolPolicy: cloudfront.ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
  viewerCertificate: cloudfront.ViewerCertificate.fromAcmCertificate(cert, {
    aliases: [recordName],
    sslMethod: cloudfront.SSLMethod.SNI,
    securityPolicy: cloudfront.SecurityPolicyProtocol.TLS_V1_2_2021
  }),
});

const cfnDistribution = cfDist.node.defaultChild as cloudfront.CfnDistribution;
cfnDistribution.addPropertyOverride(
  'DistributionConfig.DefaultCacheBehavior.ResponseHeadersPolicyId',
  cloudfront.ResponseHeadersPolicy.SECURITY_HEADERS.responseHeadersPolicyId
);
```

Now I want to add CSP headers to my setup. I am not sure where and how to add this to my current setup. Can anyone guide me on how to add CSP headers to my current setup? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

See [Customizing Response Headers with Response Headers Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront-readme.html#customizing-response-headers-with-response-headers-policies) in the AWS CDK docs:

```js
// Creating a custom response headers policy -- all parameters optional
const myResponseHeadersPolicy = new cloudfront.ResponseHeadersPolicy(this, 'ResponseHeadersPolicy', {
  responseHeadersPolicyName: 'MyPolicy',
  comment: 'A default policy',
  corsBehavior: {
    accessControlAllowCredentials: false,
    accessControlAllowHeaders: ['X-Custom-Header-1', 'X-Custom-Header-2'],
    accessControlAllowMethods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    accessControlAllowOrigins: ['*'],
    accessControlExposeHeaders: ['X-Custom-Header-1', 'X-Custom-Header-2'],
    accessControlMaxAge: Duration.seconds(600),
    originOverride: true,
  },
  customHeadersBehavior: {
    customHeaders: [
      { header: 'X-Amz-Date', value: 'some-value', override: true },
      { header: 'X-Amz-Security-Token', value: 'some-value', override: false },
    ],
  },
  securityHeadersBehavior: {
    contentSecurityPolicy: { contentSecurityPolicy: 'default-src https:;', override: true },
    contentTypeOptions: { override: true },
    frameOptions: { frameOption: cloudfront.HeadersFrameOption.DENY, override: true },
    referrerPolicy: { referrerPolicy: cloudfront.HeadersReferrerPolicy.NO_REFERRER, override: true },
    strictTransportSecurity: { accessControlMaxAge: Duration.seconds(600), includeSubdomains: true, override: true },
    xssProtection: { protection: true, modeBlock: true, reportUri: 'https://example.com/csp-report', override: true },
  },
  removeHeaders: ['Server'],
  serverTimingSamplingRate: 50,
});
new cloudfront.Distribution(this, 'myDistCustomPolicy', {
  defaultBehavior: {
    origin: bucketOrigin,
    responseHeadersPolicy: myResponseHeadersPolicy,
  },
});
```